# Does $\pi$ have infinitely many prime prefixes?

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, formal-languages, pi

*This is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2285471/104041).*

> Does $\pi$ have infinitely many prime prefixes (in base $10$)? That is, is the sequence [A005042](http://oeis.org/A005042) infinite?

It says on the OEIS that a naïve probabilistic argument suggests that the sequence of such primes is infinite. What argument would that be?

Such primes would be examples of [pi-primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi-Prime.html).

Comment: I would expect that this will be related somehow to the normality of $\pi$ which has not yet been proven.  If $\pi$ were truly normal, without calculating the true digits of $\pi$ ahead of time for any value of $n$ the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ should have a positive (i.e. nonzero) probability to be prime.  That should be enough to imply the sequence is infinite.

Comment: Even, if $\pi$ is not normal, there is a chance that there are infinite many pi-primes. But since we cannot even rule out that the digits of $\pi$ are eventually $0,2,4,5,6,8$ or even $0$ and $2$ , a decision of the question is probably completely out of reach. If we assume random digits, probably infinite many pi-primes exist.