# Does the golden ratio have infinitely many prime prefixes?

Tags: prime-numbers, formal-languages, golden-ratio

> Does the [golden ratio](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $\phi$ have infinitely many prime prefixes? That is, is the sequence [A064117](https://oeis.org/A064117) infinite?

I'm guessing that $\phi$ does have infinitely many prime prefixes if $\phi$ is normal, similar to [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289380/does-pi-have-infinitely-many-prime-prefixes#comment4709995_2289380) on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289380/does-pi-have-infinitely-many-prime-prefixes) about $\pi$.

Comment: I don't think there is much of a difference between the questions, really, given our limited state of knowledge.  The same heuristic arguments could apply to any number where the digits "seem random" (and I believe $\phi$ is conjectured to be normal.)